# Cant figure out what wrong with my Manifest XML file

Tags: android, xml

Estoy tratando de generar una pantalla de inicio en mi aplicación colocando un filtro de intención en mi XML de manifiesto, pero sigue diciendo que el filtro de intención es incorrecto e inesperado y creo que estoy cerrando las etiquetas, ¡bien! ¡Por favor ayuda! No entiendo por qué sigue diciéndome que está mal... He intentado cerrar cada etiqueta manualmente, pero soy realmente un principiante en esto, así que podría estar equivocado. Dice "elemento inesperado  encontrado en <aplicación>". en la terminal. Tengo 3 actividades, antes de que esta actividad de inicio de sesión fuera la del iniciador, ahora quiero que la bienvenida esté activada primero. ¡Gracias!

Estoy depurando esto en un teléfono en vivo y sigue eliminando la pestaña de cierre en la actividad de presentación, es por eso que no lo veran en este código.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ardisatoven"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="32" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ARdiSAToven" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ardisatoven.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ardisatoven.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ardisatoven.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.ardisatoven.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola, por favor escribe tu consulta en Español. Si tu pregunta es en inlges puedes hacerlo en https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Gracias! no me di cuenta

Comment: Pero no eliminaste ni traduciste la pregunta...

Comment: Listo, gracias por responder!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Esto soluciono mi problema. Tenia una cuestion de los comentarios en .XML , mal abiertos y mal cerrados.

En Build->Clean Project se eliminan los tags agregados de forma extra , arreglando el codigo y quedandome asi:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ARdiSAToven">
    <activity
        android:name=".ConnectActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:exported="false"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true"></activity>
</application>
```

Paso enlace que muestra como solucionarlo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56MbbgcCk6c

Comment: Estás en [es.so], la pregunta y su respuesta debe ir **en español**. Además, no respondas con solo un enlace.